# viewing a local pdf file in google chrome packaged apps

Tags: google-chrome, fileapi, google-chrome-app

In my packaged app I would like to open pdf's stored in local filesystem. I've managed to open them if I select them using `chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry`, but I can't find a way to do the same if the filesnames are hard coded.

The idea behind is an app that manages book information and allows to open them if they are stored in the local filesystem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done, for good reason. Packaged apps have a security model based on the open web. Web pages can't access your local files without your permission (i.e., without a "user gesture" or a specific user action such as going through a file chooser), and packaged apps have the same restriction.

You could import local files (again using a user gesture) into the [HTML5 file system](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/), or into [chrome.syncFileSystem](http://developer.chrome.com/dev/apps/syncFileSystem.html). Then you'd have gestureless access to the imported copies. Likewise, you could export from either of those file systems to the local file system, again with a user gesture. But the boundary between local files and your app's access to them is meant to be loud and explicit.

Comment: Correct, except the "good reason" part.  Packaged apps do not have to be on the web (which is a major reason for using them), so there is no good reason to restrict a local packaged app from using local files with the user's permission.  Maybe Google will listen if enough people demand it and don't take "security" as the answer for everything that has not been thought out properly.